Deploy stored procedure in synapse built in SQL database with private endpoint
We have a synapse workspace configured with Private endpoint. We want to deploy a stored procedure in Synapse built-in sql via azure devops. The script is in our repo and I have created a release pipeline.
The release pipeline is having 2 tasks. One is to deploy artifacts to synapse workspace. Second one is create stored procedure in built-in database.
For second one, I am using 'Azure SQL database deployment' task and provided built-in server name and SQL script.
However the second step fails with below error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
was not accessible.

Since Synapse has private end point, we are using devops self-hosted agent and are able to deploy Synapse code, I am assuming it should be able to access built-in SQL as well.
Can someone please help any guidance on this.

On your sef-hosted agent, you can try to connect to the built-in sql via SSMS to check the connection, is it succesful?

@wadezhou-MSFT: We don't have SSMS on our self hosted agent but we tried Test-Connection and that failed. Does that mean there is a problem connecting to serverless from self hosted agent pool? Also, we are able to connect Synapse (which also has PE) from our devops self hosted agent (synapse deployment pipeline runs fine) so not sure why serverless pool we can't.

It could be. But it's still recommended to install SSMS on agent and try the connection with it as mentioned in official doc, it also validate other causes, like credential...etc. In addition,which option did you set for private endpoint? check the 3 type options in doc.

In addition, on agent, access synapse workspace -> sql pool from browser, is the status Online or Unreachable? It should be Online.

may i know if the built-in server can be reached from agent now?


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

The error indicates the agent cannot connect to the built-in sql, it could happen by different causes, eg: network is not reached as private endpoint configured, credential is not correct...etc.
It's recommended to log on the DevOps agent machine, test connection to sql via SSMS as mentioned in doc.
In addition, please go to azure portal, access synapse workspace -> sql pool, make sure the sql is Online status.
You need fix the connection, make sure agent can connect to the built-in sql, then try again the pipeline.
